# Automatize multiple calls for an API with requests python module

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to get some data from the [RePEc API](https://ideas.repec.org/api.html). I have my access code.

I need that `offset` parameter increase in 25 for each solicitude starting in 0 and stops when don't have an answer back. Also I need that `getrecentjel` parameter goes from E1 to E7.

The calls I need to do are:

**1.** `getrecentjel=E1` with `offset=0`, `offset=25`, `offset=50` (`offset` parameter should increase for 25 *in each call* until not get an answer back from the API)... and store all the data in a file.

**2.** `getrecentjel=E2` with `offset=0`, `offset=25`, `offset=50` (`offset` parameter should increase for 25 *in each call* until not get an answer back from the API)... and store all the data in a file.

**3.** `getrecentjel=E3` with `offset=0`, `offset=25`, `offset=50` (`offset` parameter should increase for 25 *in each call* until not get an answer back from the API)... and store all the data in a file.

**4.** `getrecentjel=E4` with `offset=0`, `offset=25`, `offset=50` (`offset` parameter should increase for 25 *in each call* until not get an answer back from the API)... and store all the data in a file.

**5.** `getrecentjel=E5` with `offset=0`, `offset=25`, `offset=50` (`offset` parameter should increase for 25 *in each call* until not get an answer back from the API)... and store all the data in a file.

**6.** `getrecentjel=E6` with `offset=0`, `offset=25`, `offset=50` (`offset` parameter should increase for 25 *in each call* until not get an answer back from the API)... and store all the data in a file.

**7.** `getrecentjel=E7` with `offset=0`, `offset=25`, `offset=50` (`offset` parameter should increase for 25 *in each call* until not get an answer back from the API)... and store all the data in a file.

This is how I try do it.

```
import requests as rq
import json

if __name__ == "__main__":
    url="https://api.repec.org/call.cgi"
payload={"code" : "code", "offset" : 25, "getrecentjel" : "E", "repecservice" : "ideas"}
response = rq.get(url,params=payload)
print ("url call form:", response.url)

if response.status_code==200: 
    print("Petición correcta y almacenada")
    content = response.content
    datos = open("JEL.json","wb")
    datos.write(content)
    datos.close()
else:
    print("Status:", response, "por favor verificar")
```

It is obvious that with my code, I should increase `offset` and `getrecentjel` parameter by hand, it means change its value for each solicitude. I really appreciate find a way to automate the calls.